# Warning message with Nokogiri and Open-Uri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, windows-subsystem-for-linux, open-uri

Hello I have an error message which is the following :

warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open

I don't understand why there is this message, I also tried the URI.open ("link") command. Read

But I have to use Nokogiri.

Here is my code:

```html
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


puts "Wait a second data is coming..."


PAGE_URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))


currency_name_array = page.xpath("//tr/td/a[contains(@class, 'currency-name-container')]/text()").map {|x| x.to_s }

currency_value_array = page.xpath("//tr/td/a[contains(@class, 'price')]/text()").map {|x| x.to_s }


currency_result = Hash[currency_name_array.zip(currency_value_array)]

puts currency_result
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as the warning suggests "URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated" so instead replace `Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))` with `Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(PAGE_URL))`. Previously `require 'open-uri'` modified the way `Kernel#open` functioned to allow for the uri functionality but this is hacky and thus was deprecated

Comment: Thanks ! Its help me !

Comment: @engineersmnky - thanks for the solution! Worked for me using ruby 3.1.3.